# What is the difference between sqrtPriceLimitX96 and amountOutMinimum for uniswap?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3, mev, sqrtpricelimitx96, amountoutminimum

The sqrtPriceLimitX96 is just a price limit which cannot be exceeded by the trade.

At the same time, the amountOutMinimum appears to do the same thing in that you can achieve maximum price by taking:

`amountIn / amountOutMinimum`

So let's say we're talking about WETH/USDC on arbitrum. Arbitrum is easier because it's USDC/WETH (token 1 / token 0) for price. So let's say price is currently $1,500.

If you are willing to put in $1,600 USDC for an amount out minimum of 1 WETH then the worst price you're willing to accept is $1,600 USDC per WETH.

This to me is the same as using a $1,600 USDC / 1 WETH price limit.

Can someone please explain the difference. The ever wonderful miss Rachel in the dev discord was unfortunately unable to explain this, though I assume the uni devs have a very good reason for this as they do for most things.

Comment: This is the limit price, not the average sales price

Comment: If you'd like to expand on this with examples I think it would make for a nice answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `sqrtPriceLimitX96` and `amountOutMinimum` serve as protective measures for traders on Uniswap V3, but they operate at different levels and have distinct behavioral implications.

#### sqrtPriceLimitX96:

**Operational Level:** This parameter is integrated into the core `UniswapV3Pool` contract, which handles the fundamental operations of liquidity provision and swaps.

**Function:** It establishes a price boundary for a swap. During a trade on Uniswap V3, as liquidity is utilized and price shifts, the `sqrtPriceLimitX96` ensures the price doesn't go beyond this pre-defined limit. If the `sqrtPriceX96` at the very start of the swap exceeds the `sqrtPriceLimitX96` in the swap direction then the swap will revert with `SPL`.

**Behavioral Implication:** This parameter allows for partial trades. Meaning, if the trade would breach this price before exhausting the `amountSpecified`, the system will only trade up to the limit, potentially using less than the full `amountSpecified`.

#### amountOutMinimum:

**Operational Level:** This parameter is employed at the higher-level `SwapRouter` interface, which interacts with the core pool contracts and offers an abstracted method for users to conduct trades.

**Function:** It mandates a minimum amount of the output token the trader must receive for the swap to be valid. After the swap is executed, the resultant amount of the output token is compared to this value.

**Behavioral Implication:** It acts as an all-or-nothing check post-swap. If the resultant output from the swap is less than the `amountOutMinimum`, the entire transaction is reverted. This is independent of whether the `sqrtPriceLimitX96` was adhered to during the swap.

**Summary:** While both parameters help traders define the bounds of their trades, they do so in different ways. The `sqrtPriceLimitX96` offers low-level control, allowing partial trades up to a specified price, whereas `amountOutMinimum` provides a high-level post-trade check ensuring the trader receives a minimum desired return.

By using both, Uniswap V3 offers traders a combination of precise control (through `sqrtPriceLimitX96`) and a safety check (through `amountOutMinimum`), optimizing both flexibility and security.

Comment: `sqrtPriceLimitX96` and partial prices are useful for arbitration, as one can say "give me any amount of token X at a price Y".

Comment: @kfx I use ChatGPT to improve my wording and structure, don't see anything wrong with that. Also `amountOutMinimum` is not on the core `UniswapV3Pool#swap` function but on the `SwapRouter#exactInputSingle` function which is a periphery contract.

Comment: @kfx `sqrtPriceLimitX96` is a parameter to the `UniswapV3Pool#swap` function.
https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/d8b1c635c275d2a9450bd6a78f3fa2484fef73eb/contracts/interfaces/pool/IUniswapV3PoolActions.sol#L79

Comment: So if you breach the sqrt price limit you get the error "SPL" which rolls back the entire transaction as well. So I do not think this is accurate. https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/d8b1c635c275d2a9450bd6a78f3fa2484fef73eb/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol#L612. Also ChatGPT is horrible when it comes to uniswap question in my experience.

Comment: @Nat it only reverts with `SPL` if the starting spot price for the pool already exceeds the input limit price in the swap's direction, but if it does not then the swap will proceed until either `amountSpecified` is entirely used(if amountIn)/given(if amount out) or until the `sqrtPriceLimitX96` is reached. So `SPL` is more of a pre-validation check.

Comment: ok edit the answer with something small so I can upvote it again please. Perhaps add info on the SPL pre check.

Comment: @Nat ok, I just did.

Comment: So in short this is just incorrect https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/core/UniswapV3Pool#parameters-7.

Comment: @Nat the statement: "If zero for one, the price cannot be less than this value after the swap. If one for zero, the price cannot be greater than this value after the swap" is NOT incorrect. As the `sqrtPriceLimitX96` variable essentially means that the swap should stop at that price even if there is still an amount remaining.

Comment: Is it recommended to set `sqrtPriceLimitX96` to 0? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: @anonauditor if you don't want the swap to stop at a price, then you can set `sqrtPriceLimitX96` to the max price if your swap moves the price upwards or to the min price if you swap moves the price downwards.